# Need assistance with a Google Sheet and an auto email function

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I have a very simple need and I think a script will be able to do this. I have a order tracking sheet with many rows of data and in column Q my team is supposed to enter a date of acknowledgement. Well, at times this process gets overlooked.

I would like to have a script which checks to see which cells in Q are blank, and send me (and my team) a list of the empty cells, but refer to them with labels from the data in A , B , C & D and make a reference to the entry date which is in column P. This way, I am not hunting for cells, but the script is sending me an email of a list which is easy to read.

The email only has to say something like :
"The following orders have not yet been acknowledged:

1. TextfromA, TextfromB, TextfromC, TextfromD sent to vendor on DatefromP
2. TextfromA, TextfromB, TextfromC, TextfromD sent to vendor on DatefromP
3. TextfromA, TextfromB, TextfromC, TextfromD sent to vendor on DatefromP
   etc....

Once the Q cell is populated, it should be ignored by the script. I would like the script to email me and the team this current list every 72 hours. Also, if at all possible I would like to ignore certain rows (which are like headers). If we can't, that's fine.

I know it's probably very simple, but I do need some help!!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a fairly simple script, what have you come up with on your own?

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a hint to get you started:**

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh=ss.getSheetByName('tracking sheet');
var rg=sh.getDataRange();
var dataA=rg.getValues();
var message=''
for(var i=0;i<dataA.length;i++){
  if(!dataA[i][16]){
    message+=dataA[i][0] + ', ' + dataA[i][1] + ', ' + dataA[i][2] + ', ' + dataA[i][3] + '\n';
  }
}
if(message.length>0){
  //Send Emails
}
```